# How do I set a max length of a string in a conteneditable table in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, string, html-table, maxlength

I have currently been making a word search maker, but I have occurred a problem. The problem is that I'me using a table with contenteditable, but how do I set a max string length. I already tried

`maxlength="1"`

Can anyone please help!

```css
#editor {
  background-color: turquoise;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" id="editor" width="500px" height="500px">
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When running to code snippet, please go fullscreen.

Please, if there are any ways, please try avoid jquery!

Comment: Surely you could've created a smaller example? (What does a 12x12 table show us that a 4x4 table wouldn't?)

Comment: I really don't think `contenteditable` is the way to go here. If you want the behavior of an input (e.g. a `maxlength` property) use an input.

Comment: @Corey Ogbum I've already tried that, but no luck for me because the width and height just won't follow along with the css I tried. Though now, I kind of gave up on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either change those to inputs, or use the following JavaScript

```js
var pre = onload, doc, T, oneCharOnly; // change pre to another var if using technique on different page
onload = function(){
if(pre)pre();
  
doc = document;
T = function(n, e){
  var w = e || doc;
  return w.getElementsByTagName(n);
}
oneCharOnly = function(){
  var tds = T('td');
  for(var i=0,l=tds.length; i<l; i++){
    tds[i].onkeyup = function(){
      if(!this.innerHTML.match(/^.$/)){
        this.contentEditable = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
oneCharOnly(); // okay to use on other pages due to scope
  
}
```

```css
#editor {
  background-color: turquoise;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" id="editor" width="500px" height="500px">
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If you type in the box really fast, then it will type in more than one letter in each box.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using javascript:

Example:

```js
const table = document.querySelector('table');

const validateMaxLength = (event) => {
  const textLength = event.target.textContent.length;

  if ( textLength > 5) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}

table.addEventListener('keydown', validateMaxLength);
```

```css
#editor {
  background-color: turquoise;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" id="editor" width="500px" height="500px">
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is OP trying to maintain the original `width` of the cells?

Comment: @guest271314 what do you mean with "OP"?

Comment: Original Post or Original Poster.

Comment: Note, could be incorrect about original poster trying maintaining `width` of cells. That is just a possibility from perspective, here.

Comment: @guest271314, yes, I am trying to maintain the original width of the cells.